# FTP client that uses Gnome Keyring?

Tags: ftp, gnome-keyring

There any ftp client that uses Gnome Keyring to store password ?

I'm quite sure there isn't any stand alone app alternative to Filezilla on Linux, that is a little to old and kind of abandon-ware and for the most save password in plan.

So I'm also interested in any plugin for chrome/firefox that is integrated with Gnome-Keyring

Answer (score 0):

You can use Nautilus for FTP. It will use your keyring.

Comment: it is not exactly the FTP client I would use for work on my customer's live sites ...

Comment: Then perhaps you should edit your question to provide feature requirements of the client you're requesting?

Comment: Also applies to XFCE's `thunar`. Integration is really good. I guess there are more file managers which satisfy this requirement, perhaps Dolphin or Commander

Comment: I guess Thunar uses GVFS?